# AnonymousEndpoint with address {uri.var.apiurl} in WSO2 EI 6.6

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I tired to send the request to an endpoint I get the AnonymousEndpoint error and when I hit the endpoint URL with request in the postman it's working fine what should I do to fix this issue.

And I even tired the markForSuspension and suspendOnFailure configuration nothing worked as excepted.

```
<property name="singleQuote" scope="default" type="STRING" value="'"/>
                        <property description="AppConfig" expression="evaluate(fn:concat('get-property(',get-property('singleQuote'),'QRSag_iAppraisal_Config_',get-property('clientOrg'),get-property('singleQuote'),')' ))" name="AppConfig" scope="default" type="OM"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:AppConfig//*[local-name()='laravel_url']/text()" name="uri.var.apiurl" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <property expression="$ctx:AppConfig//*[local-name()='authorization']/text()" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
                        <!--  
                        <log level="custom">
                        <property name="uri.var.apiurl :::::::::::::::::::   " expression="$ctx:uri.var.apiurl"/>
                        <property name="Authorization :::::::::::::::::::   " expression="$trp:Authorization"/>
                        </log> -->
                       <call description="VB iAppraisal Endpoint">
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="post" uri-template="{uri.var.apiurl}"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                        <!--  <log level="custom">
                        <property name="Laravel API Response :::::::::::::::::::   " expression="json-eval($.)"/>
                        </log> -->
```

[image: Log Error]

Comment: Hi @Thamu,
Can you please check whether values (uri.var.apiurl, Authorization) comes from local entry or not?

Comment: Thanks Justin!! The values are not retrieving from the local entry after some changes in the local entry property now the endpoint error fixed.                                                              `<property expression="get-property('QRSag_iAppraisal_Config_VBUat')" name="AppConfig" scope="default" type="OM"/>`